# Android SoftKeyboard on SurfaceView

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the Soft Keyboard on a SurfaceView in my game. Problem is I can't handle onKey events.

I've tried implementing an OnKeyListener on my view, and overriding:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.w("Key", "Key Pressed");
    return true;
}
```

But I don't receive any key events.

Using

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.w("Key", "Key Pressed");
    return true;
}
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had to specify the following on the view constructor hook:

```
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

since input events are only sent to the focused view.